# Why is jQuery returning undefined when I try to access an element's data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to access the data attribute of a checkbox to pass through to a PHP script to update my database.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-entid="1"onchange="updateOrDeleteEntitlements()" 
checked>
```

The jQuery function is:

```
 function updateOrDeleteEntitlements() {
    var role = $('#selectedRole').val();
    var ent = $(this).data('entid');
    var binMe = '';

     $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/update_delete_entitlements.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'role': $role, 'ent': ent, 'delete': $binMe},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }); 
 }
```

The line `var ent = $(this).data('entid');` should be storing the data held in the checkbox so I can pass it through in my AJAX but is returning undefined.

Spent around an hour trying some slightly different things but nothing seems to work. I've also used this same exact thing elsewhere in my code (but pulling data from a tr rather than input) so I'm completely beffudled.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: script rather can't realize what is `$(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*this* doesn't referes to the checkbox element it refers to `window` object. You need to pass the current element i.e. `this` in the inline-change event handler and in the method accept it and later use it to retrieve the data.

*HTML*

```
<input type="checkbox" data-entid="1"onchange="updateOrDeleteEntitlements(this)" checked>
```

*Script*

```
function updateOrDeleteEntitlements(elem) { 
    var ent = $(elem).data('entid');    
}
```

---

I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handling technique. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method attach the event handler. Using it, `this` will refer to the checkbox hence you code will work.

*HTML*

```
<input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-entid="1" checked>
```

*Script*

```
$('.myCheckbox').on('change', updateOrDeleteEntitlements)
```

```js
$('.myCheckbox').on('change', updateOrDeleteEntitlements);

function updateOrDeleteEntitlements() {
  var ent = $(this).data('entid');
  console.log(ent)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-entid="1" checked>
```

Answer (score 4):

You call the function without context, and so `this` is not the element you think it should be.

You can set the context as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-entid="1" onchange="updateOrDeleteEntitlements.call(this)">
```

However, it is usually considered better to attach event handlers in code, without the `onchange` attribute. You would then add this line in your main script:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(updateOrDeleteEntitlements);
```

Adapt the selector passed to `$()` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
var ent = $(this).data('entid');
```

you intended to get the `data-entid` property of your `checkbox`, but this is not your checkbox. Untested suggestion:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-entid="1"onchange="updateOrDeleteEntitlements(this)" 
checked>
```

and

```
 function updateOrDeleteEntitlements(context) {
    var role = $('#selectedRole').val();
    var ent = $(context).data('entid');
    var binMe = '';

     $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/update_delete_entitlements.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'role': $role, 'ent': ent, 'delete': $binMe},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }); 
 }
```